# Golang change xml marshal format of float

Tags: xml, go, format, marshalling

When I marshal `float64` to an xml file:

```
type X struct {
    Value float64 `xml:",attr,omitempty"`
}
var x X
x.Value = 1000000.04
```

I get value like:

```
<X Value="1.00000004e+06"></X>
```

How to change the output format, such that the full value (1000000.04) is written (and the `omitempty` tag is still working)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own number type that marshals the way you like it:

```
type prettyFloat float64

func (f prettyFloat) MarshalXMLAttr(name xml.Name) (xml.Attr, error) {
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", f)
    return xml.Attr{Name: name, Value: s}, nil
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/2moWdAwXrd.

**EDIT:** `,omitempty` version:

```
type prettyFloat float64

func (f prettyFloat) MarshalXMLAttr(name xml.Name) (xml.Attr, error) {
    if f == 0 {
        return xml.Attr{}, nil
    }
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", f)
    return xml.Attr{Name: name, Value: s}, nil
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/myBrjGGSJY.

Comment: Thank you! How would I handle the `omitempty` xml tag? Now `0.00` gets written to the attribute. (added edit to question)

Comment: Ok, I see. Currently on the phone so I haven't tried it yet, but wouldn't a float like `0.000000012252` mess it up?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "messing it up".

Comment: As an option closer to the go implementation: https://play.golang.org/p/DK9wDZ2d_I   

It uses strconv